# Error en conseguir id en php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php5

Tengo una aplicacion web y tiene un registro y un inicio de sesion, tengo dos headers para que uno se muestre cuando el usuario no se ha logueado y otro para cuando ya se logue. pero cuando intento tomar datos del array para ponerlo en un input de tipo hidden me da error

```
    <?php session_start();

require_once "views/extras/header.php";
require_once "views/extras/header-log.php";


if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}

$errores = '';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $email = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['email']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password = hash('sha512', $password);

    try {
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=empleos', 'root', '');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();;
    }

    $statement = $conexion->prepare('
        SELECT * FROM userslog WHERE email = :email AND password = :password'
    );
    $statement->execute(array(
        ':email' => $email,
        ':password' => $password
    ));

    $resultado = $statement->fetch();
    if ($resultado !== false) {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $resultado;
        header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
        $errores .= '<li>Datos Incorrectos</li>';
    }
}

require 'views/login.php';

require_once "views/extras/footer.php"; 
?>
```

ese es mi codigo de login

y este es el link de todo mi 
[proyecto](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AmvS5ucAncFGg2-0QZnb8xHWlrJS)

Answer (score 0):

En vez de mandar al index , manda al dashboard
 `header('Location: dasboard.php');`

En el dashboard en la primera linea pones algo parecido asi

```
<?php
include 'session_star.php';
?>
```

En mi caso es session_star.php  el tuyo puede ser index.php ya que este archivo me permite comprobar si hay una session activa ,tengo lo siguiente

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['idusuario'])) {
  header('Location: login-turista.php');
die();
```

}
y  ahi puedes mandar que si no existe la session te regrese al login..saludos

Comment: al momento de querer introducir el id o email en el input me marca el siguiente erro ````<input type="hidden" name="<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\talvez\views\perfil.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
Array">
                    <input type="hidden" name="<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: email in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\talvez\views\perfil.php</b> on line <b>25</b><br />
">
````

Comment: En realidad no he corrido tu codigo no lo vi completo si me mostraras esa parte ,por favor

Comment: Claro, en el dashboard hice lo que me dijiste, solo mande a llamar al index con un include.

Tengo un formulario que quiero llenar con los datos que vengan de la BD 

````<form action="perfil.php" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo($_SESSION['id_user'])  ?>">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Nombre(s)</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre(s)">
                      </div>````
Le puse un print_r pero solo quiero el id no todo

Comment: tratas de poner el array asi ?  <div id="turistas"> <?php echo $_SESSION['idusuario']; ?>  </div>

Comment: Trato de poner el id en el input para poder almacenarlo en la base de datos y que asi tenga relacion la informacion con la del usuario que se logeo, no se si me eplico, puse como me dijiste pero me marco lo mismo de la conversion

Comment: ya te entendi mandas un arreglo usuario en la variable session , prueba esto    echo $_SESSION[‘usuario’][1];

Comment: :O si pudiera te besaria!!! jajaja me has salvado la vida muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Bien jajaj saludos